# how to make function calls synchronously inside evaluate?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, nightmare

Hi Am doing an automation using PhantomJS combined with nightmare, I need to make a DB call once my UI automation via nightmare is executed am making use of the evaluate function of nightmare to make the DB call what i expected was that the call will be made synchronously but what actually happens is that my DB function is triggered first before the UI automation execution gets completed as a result am passing incorrect data for DB verification .
    Below is a sample of ma code

```
exports.rejectProcess = function (testData, resultfolder, ConnectionStrings) {
    "use strict";

    return function (nightmare) {
        nightmare
            .waitForEnable('#Process')
            .click('#Process')
            .wait()
            .waitForNotVisible('div.spinnerFullLight')
            .waitForEnable('#createProcess')
            .click('#createProcess')
            .wait()
            .click('#ContinueBtn')
            .wait()
            ....etc

            .evaluate(

            function ()
             {
            var element = document.querySelector('#ProcessNumber');
            return { data: element.value }
            }, 
            function (result) {
                nightmare
               .waitForEnable("#spanDashBoardArrowd")
                .click("#spanDashBoardArrowd")
                .waitForVisible("#topNavdropdownSubMenu")
                .click("#navApprovals")
                .wait()
                ...etc
                 .click("#Reject")
                .evaluate(function () { nightmare.wait(60000);},valuateDB(testData, ConnectionStrings, result.data))
        })
    }
};

function valuateDB(testData, ConnectionStrings,concessionNumber)
{
    console.log(concessionNumber);
    var ApprovalInfo = dataOperation.getRejectStatus(testData, ConnectionStrings, concessionNumber); ------->place where i make the DB call
console.log(ApprovalInfo);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you're using PhantomJS? The newest version uses Electron under the hood.

Comment: Am not sure about that.am new to phantomJS

Comment: Which nightmare version are you using? Do you see the page when it is running and doing its thing?

Comment: Is the DB something you're pulling from client-side javascript?

Comment: No I couldn't see the pages in live but i used screenshot function to take screenshots at the background..And abt the DB call yes am calling the DB using a JavaScript function

Comment: What version of Nightmare are you on?